# How can I make new slides in powerpoint blank by default?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2016

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eYou.png)

I want to disable this stupid text that I have to manually remove from new slides globally for all current and future presentations.

Comment: You shouldn't have to delete it: double-click and start typing; the place-holder text disappears.

Comment: You might also wish to [Create your own default presentation](https://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ01010_Create_your_own_default_presentation.htm).

Comment: I tried making a template but that only makes the first slide blank with no place holders, when  I make a new slide within the presentation, the place holders appear.  I use powerpoint to manage projects, not to make slideshows.  So although they aren't visible during slideshows, the fact that they are during the main editor screen causes me an inconveinence in deleting them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the text box?

If not, I suggest you go to View > Slide Master, delete the text box of Office Theme Slide Master and the Title Slide layout.

[image]

Then close Master View.

Delete the first slide and insert new blank slide.

[image]